# Python terminal error

Tags: python

Just wondering how can I fix this error?

```
python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
```

another example:

```
python --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not define
```

Comment: @arshajii: Oops, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

The command `python` is run on the command prompt. `python` is not a command in Python.

Open a command prompt (it's called `cmd` on Windows and `Terminal` on OSX), and then type one of the commands you are trying to use.

```
C:\>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> print 'test'
test
>>> exit()

C:\>python --version
Python 2.7.2

C:\>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I was a little confused when setting this up.

Answer (score 3):

You get a Python error; that means you are already *in* the Python interpreter. As such, you don’t need to (or can even) execute the Python executable again.

If you want to quit the interpreter, press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then you will be able to call `python` or `python --version` again.